# Javascript[PURE] go to the saved link in object and fetch data (DevConsole)

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

Hello everyone I have a object like this one in developer console saved in localstorage

```
 let obj = [{
name: "Cambridge University",
link: "https://www.cam.ac.uk/colleges-and-departments/department-a-z"
},
{
name: "University Of Bradford",
link: "https://www.bradford.ac.uk/study/faculties/"
}]
```

I need to go to links inside of objects and get dept names for example:

Go to obj[link] (first one) -> let x = document.querySelectorAll('li') -> Update obj like

```
obj[{
 name: "Cambridge University",
  link: "https://www.cam.ac.uk/colleges-and-departments/department-a-z",
  depts: ["li1","li2"]
}]
```

How can i do this?

Comment: You really must show some more code. Please add relevant HTML and expected output. Why developer console?

Comment: I have a html like <a href="/tr/xx/xx-xx-xx-xx">xx</a> I saved this link to the object (I have 180 element like this), I saved in to the localstorage and I need to go these links and run some codes on the developer console (why dev console: because I am trying to get datas from already created website I try to get html element's innerTexts)

Comment: So for example: go obj[link] -> run let x =  document.querySelectorAll('xx') -> save this one to the already created object like obj[description] = xx

Comment: Update the question instead of posting html and code in comments

Comment: What is `name` and where is it from. Can you perhaps no use xxx,xxx and update the question with what you are actually doing when and where?